# Input Variable Scaling Method Using Regression Coefficient

Tags: feature-selection

I am reading a paper with tite: Input Variable Scaling Method using Regression Coefficient.

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwid7Nn28sndAhXCdisKHUzEBBkQFjAAegQIBBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.jstage.jst.go.jp%2Farticle%2Fjacc%2F57%2F0%2F57_1161%2F_pdf%2F-char%2Fja&usg=AOvVaw2pTznMe76xUXqnnpSouBrC

There are some steps to be involved:

1. Prepare the raw input variable matrix `X` and an output `y`
2. Set an iteration number `i` to 1 and the maximum iteration number to
       ***I***.
3. Calculate the initial input variable scaling factor matrix using
   diagonal matrix standard deviation (row base), `b`
4. Derive the scaled input `X*` Calculate new input variable scaling
   factor from VIP, `b*`
5. Calculate the new scaled input `X*new` Continue up to max iteration.

My Question is refer to the iteration, exactly is this iteration similar to like bootstrap or monte carlo? If yes how its written in R? thanks